# Modeling database to support complex company-product-price relationship

Tags: database, database-design

In software that we are building we have a parent-child relationship between companies (one company can only have one parent company but can have multiple child companies) and we need to adjust our product pricing for every company.
[image]

Here is a quick db model of how it should look like but this Company-PriceCatalogs-CompanyCatalogs relationship smells fishy.

Idea is that Company gets charged by PriceCatalog assigned to it by it's parent company (this direct relationship between Company and PriceCatalogs), but company can also have multiple different price catalogs that can be assign to one or more of it's child companies (and that is this Company-CompanyCatalogs-PriceCatalogs relationship).
I cannot think of smarter solutions at this point and solution above doesn't feel right for some reason.
Does anyone have any advice?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So at the end I ended up deleting relationship between Company and Catalog and added CatalogType to the CompanyCatalogs table (type being is it assigned or is it catalog that can be assigned)[image]